# auto-check Selenium questions

Tags: feature-request

I believe most Selenium questions do not start out with enough information to provide an answer.  Is there a proactive way to encourage the questioner to provide that information?  For example, if someone uses the "Selenium" tag (or a related tag), show them a reminder of what they need to provide, e.g. locator, code, and HTML.

Comment: I like this idea, although I'd think it's a stack code improvement, Would this be just for SQA or all tags should suggest specific things?  It might be difficult since tags can be added by new posts when they aren't there yet...